# how to define $\frac{df}{d\Omega}$ derivative with respect to solid angle?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, spherical-coordinates

In a physics course we could define the [scattering cross section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_section_(physics)) written $\frac{dN}{d\Omega}$ counting the number of particles going through a certain area of the sphere over a certain amount of time.  Is it possible to give mathematical definition of the derivative with respect to [solid angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle)?

Let $f: S^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be some sort of real-valued function on the sphere, we could try to define the "derivative" at a point by:

$$ f(x_0) = \lim_{|\epsilon| \to 0}  \frac{1}{\pi \epsilon^2} \int_{B_\epsilon(x_0) \cap S^2} f(x) \,d\Omega $$

Here $\Omega = \frac{A}{r^2}$ could be measured in [steradians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steradian).  We could try to recover the value at a point using the fundamental theorem of calculus.

This is just like differentiating [under the integral sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) with the same kinds of mistakes. Does this limit necessarily exist?  I could imagine a very chaotic function real-valued function $f$ defined on $S^2$ and we could integrate over a sequence of regions $\Omega_n \to \{ x_0\}$ and yet the limit doesn't exist.

---

Lots of discussions on Math.SE of sphere integrals where the formulas are well-defined.
[Surface Integral over a sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909852/surface-integral-over-a-sphere)

Comment: I haven't used solid angles before, but in a pinch can't we just say $\mathrm{d}\Omega=\mathrm{D}_r\{A/r^2\}\mathrm{d}r$ ?